# How to use the value of `useSelector()` in click event handlers?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Foll is a outline of the code. I am getting outdated 'cartSize'.

```
function CartComp(props) {
  const [cartSize, setCartSize] = useState(0);

const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);

useEffect(() => {
  setCartSize(() => {
    return cartList.length;
  });
}, [cartList]);

const onClickAddBtn = (cartObj) => {
  if (cartSize > 4) { // outdated state
    alert(`cannot add more than ${cartSize} items`);
  }
}
<button
onClick={onClickAddBtn.bind(this, cartObj)}
>
Add
</button>
}
```

basically, on clicking on , need to fetch `cartSize` for logical purpose.
useSelector() gives an array `cartList`, whose `length` is set as `setCartSize`.
so, when `cartSize` is accessed, it is giving value, one step behind. ie on clicking `<button>`, the `cartList` is latest but `cartSize` is the value from previous value.

how to manage this? How to use the value of `useSelector()` in click event handlers?

EDIT-1:

// robo-list.js

```
const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.robo.cartItems);

{galleryItems.map((robo) => {
 <div>
  <CartButton list={cartList} item={robo} />
 </div>
...
```

// robot-gallery.js

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import AddShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddShoppingCart";

import { roboActions } from "../store/robo-slice";

function CartButton(props) {
  console.log("gal2: ",props.list.length);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onClickAddBtn = (len) => {
    console.log("gal1: ",len);
    if (props.list.length > 2) {
      alert(`cannot add more than ${props.cartList.length} material`);
    } else {
      dispatch(
        roboActions.updateCart({
          item: props.item,
          userAction: "addItemToCart",
        })
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      startIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon fontSize="small" />}
      disabled={props.item.stock === 0}
      onClick={onClickAddBtn}
    >
      Add
    </Button>
  );
}
export default CartButton;
```

I have removed bind() and seperated `click` code into another file called robot-gallery.js. I am passing `cartList` and clicked item `robo` into the .

still `cartList.length` inside  is one step behind. **what am I missing here?** Pls help.

full code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-goldberg-gcivk?file=/frontend/src/components/robo-list.js

EDIT 2:
// robot-list.js

// robot-gallery.js

```
function CartButton(props) {
  const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.robo.cartItems);

  console.log("gal2: ",cartList.length); // 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onClickAddBtn = () => {
    console.log("gal1: ", cartList.length);
    if (cartList && cartList.length > 2) {
      alert(`cannot add more than ${cartList.length} items`);
    } else {
      dispatch(
        roboActions.updateCart({
          item: props.item,
          userAction: "addItemToCart",
        })
      );
    }
  };
  <Button
  variant="outlined"
  startIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon fontSize="small" />}
  disabled={props.item.stock === 0}
  onClick={onClickAddBtn}
>
  Add
</Button>
```

`cartList.length > 2` is one update behind.

Comment: why not just cartList.length?... And why are you binding functions?

Comment: `cartList.length` is giving stale value, same behaviour as `cartsize`. I am binding `cartObj` to method  in order to send clicked value ie `cartObj` to click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Remove cartSize entirely. It's always going to be one render behind.

```
function CartComp(props) {
  const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);

  const onClickAddBtn = () => {
    if (cartList.length > 4) {
      alert(`cannot add more than ${cartList.length} items`);
    }
  };

  return <button onClick={onClickAddBtn}>
      Add
    </button>;
};
```

Comment: `cartList` from `const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);`,  is always up-to-date,  but `cartList` inside `onClickAddBtn()` is always one step behind.

Comment: Did you remove the `bind` as shown? Also where are dispatching the action to update state.cart.cartItems? Based on the names of your functions it seems like you probably have a race.

Comment: Because that would send the click handle event object into your function as the robo param. If you read the docs for that prop, or log the param, you will see what I mean. Simply call it with the value you want instead.

Comment: I updated code and error is gone, kindly check EDIT details in question and link for updated code. can you suggest. still `cartList` is old value.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to keep the length in sync with state? Can't you just do:

```
const CartComponent = () => {

  const cartList = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartItems);

  const onClickAddBtn = () => {
    if(cartList && cartList.length > 4) alert(`cannot add more than ${cartList.length} items`);
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={onClickAddBtn}>
      Add
    </button>
  )
}
```

You should also check that redux state is actually updated. Are you perhaps mutating state? A good practice could be to use `immer` in your reducers, to make sure your state is immutable. If it is mutated, React might not pick up on state changes as the reference to the data is not changed.

Comment: I am using redux-toolkit, which internally uses `immer`. I have reviewed code and looks ok to me, not mutating.
I made EDIT 2, (described in question) and removed `useSelector` from <RoboList\> and directly pulling data `useSelector` at <RobotGallery/>, followed your suggestions still same issue. kindly check full code at  https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-goldberg-gcivk?file=/frontend/src/components/robot-gallery.js